# Dart Shelf Post Request No Body Data

Tags: api, dart, http, post

I am building a simple API using Dart Shelf. The GET requests work fine but I can't seem to be able to access the request body for a POST request.

```dart
import 'dart:io' show InternetAddress;

import 'package:shelf/shelf.dart' show Request, Response;
import 'package:shelf/shelf_io.dart' show serve;
import 'package:shelf_router/shelf_router.dart' show Router;

void main() async {

    Router router = Router();

    router.get('/', (Request request) {
        return Response.ok('this is the base URL');
    });

    router.post('/accounts', (Request request) async{
        final body = await request.readAsString();
        print(body);
        return Response.ok(body);
    });

    final server = await serve(
        router,
        InternetAddress.anyIPv4,
        8080,
    );

    print('Serving at http://${server.address.host}:${server.port}');
}
```

When I make the request I get the 200 OK status code but where is the body data?

Comment: You're code works. I tested your code and whatever data I post to /accounts is echoed back based on `body`. Is their an exception? Some more info is needed

Comment: your code should run properly, make sure you use request form-encode, if you use postman, use body > x-www-form-urlencoded instead of using body > form-data